# Edit model - token URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want users to be able to edit a model through a different than the default URL `/merchants/:id/edit(.:format)`, which will be using a token. This token is created randomly and stored in the database.

The link I want to create will be similar to this `merchants/token-124512/edit`.

Now I want to be able to send this link to users via e-mail. The default link with the id is  `link_to "link", edit_merchant_path(@merchant, :only_path => false)`.

How would the one with token be like? Also, how can I declare this one in the routes.rb?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Solution

First of all I would suggest to use `_url` instead of `_path` in your mailer because you want to resolve full path.

Try with:

`link_to "link", edit_merchant_url(id: @merchant.token)`

## Why _url?

using `_path` will get you `<a href=merchants/token-124512/edit'>link</a>`, but in mail you want to know host as well so you should get this:
`<a href='hostname.com/merchants/token-124512/edit'>link</a>`

Answer (score 4):

If you are using rails 4, you can use the new concept called `'param'` in your routes, which will change the default route.

You can pass any field instead of your id.

```
# config/routes.rb

resources :merchants, param: :token_field

# app/controllers/merchants_controller.rb

@merchant = Merchant.find_by(token_field: params[:token_field])
```

**Example**

```js
resources :merchants, param: :your_fleld


     merchants GET  /merchants(.:format)                  merchants#index
            POST /merchants(.:format)                  merchants#create
 new_merchants GET  /merchants/new(.:format)              merchants#new
edit_merchants GET  /merchants/:your_field/edit(.:format) merchants#edit


Merchant.find_by(your_field: params[:your_field])
```

[You can find the documentation here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters)

Comment: Hai, try this and go through the documentation. I have elaborated the answer and also shown the generated routes.Please check. :-)